# php session destroy using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, json

I would like it so that when someone presses a certain link that by using ajax it will run a php file to destroy a session and when its a success the current page will remove an item from Local Storage and then the page will redirect to the index page.

currently have the following but it doesn't work

**JQUERY**

```
$('#key a').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"/assets/inc/sign-out.php",
                    data:'',
                    dataType:'html',
                    context:document.body,
                    global:false,
                    async:false,
                    success:function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                        localStorage.removeItem("logged");
                        window.location.replace('/');
                    }
                });
            });
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
include('config.php');
session_destroy();
?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the content of `config.php` but there should be a `session_start()` before `session_destroy()`

Comment: any error output? or does that success handler fire up correctly? did you try adding an error() function?

Comment: What have you done to try and debug this error?

Comment: @Adnan good point, however if session.auto_start is true, it doesn't have to be there

Comment: @ZathrusWriter, that's why I said _"I'm not sure about the content of config.php"_

Comment: using console.log no error shows up. But no data is shown either. Config.php is the database connection and session setup

Comment: @Adnan session.auto_start is a [php.ini directive](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php)

Comment: @DonaldSutherland there is nothing in console.log because php doesn't return anything. If you know directly the name of the stored session key you can try unset() it.

Comment: @ZathrusWriter.  What if he has `ini_set("session.auto_start", 1);` in the `config.php` to avoid `if (!isset($_SESSION))` ?

Comment: @Adnan session.auto_start cannot be set during runtime, PHP processes this prior to script execution

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<?php
// include 'config.php'; - does this config.php contain session related configuration like e.g. the cookie-name?

session_start(); // fetch/re-start current session
session_regenerate_id(true); // assign a new session id and delete old data
$_SESSION=array(); // empty session data
session_write_close(); // superfluous call ;-)
```

as your php script.

see http://docs.php.net/session_regenerate_id

Answer (score 0):

try this in your php:

```
session_start();
session_unset();
```